# iOS timer/wage calculator

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a timer that takes an hourly wage input and tracks how much money is made per second. The formatting on the timer works just fine but once the pennies hits 99 it zeros out and only adds to the dollars. Here is what I've got.

```
seconds = (int) (elapsedTime = (elapsedTime - (minutes *60)));
pennies = seconds * (ratePerSecond * 100);
if(pennies > 99){

    dollars++;
    pennies = 0;
}

self.moneyDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"$%02d.%02d", dollars, pennies];
```

Comment: the moneyDisplay adds the pennies up to .99 then turns into 1.00, 2.00, 3.00 ......

Comment: basically it gets stuck inside my for loop even though i reset pennies to 0.

Comment: You reset `pennies` to `0`, but the next time through the loop, you'll immediately change it to `pennies = seconds * (ratePerSecond * 100);` and it'll be over 100 again. Once it gets above 99 the first time, it'll be above 99 every single time, so every time through the loop your `if` statement will evaluate true, and you'll increment `dollars` and reset `pennies` to zero *again*, and it'll just keep doing the same thing over and over. In your code, changing `pennies` to zero affects the value you give to `self.moneyDisplay.text`, but then the loop will act as though that never happened.

Comment: Ya I realized that Paul. Thanks for the explanation of why. I couldn't figure that out. Changing it to pennies = pennies % 100; did the fix.

Comment: What loop? You didn't post any loop in your question.

Comment: by loop i meant it gets stuck in the if statement. The explanation Paul gave above perfectly explains it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
seconds = (int) (elapsedTime = (elapsedTime - (minutes *60)));
pennies = seconds * (ratePerSecond * 100);
float dollars = pennies / 100.0;
self.moneyDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"$%.2f", dollars];
```

or:

```
seconds = (int) (elapsedTime = (elapsedTime - (minutes *60)));
pennies = seconds * (ratePerSecond * 100);
int cents = pennies % 100;
int dollars = pennies / 100;
self.moneyDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"$%02d.%02d", dollars, cents];
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to do this (without if condition):

```
dollars = pennies / 100;
pennies = pennies % 100;
self.moneyDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"$%02d.%02d", dollars, pennies];
```

Note that: **The operands of the % operator shall have integer type.**

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: While down voting please add a comment why you did that. You down voting will not change me may be your explanation could.

Comment: It's a low quality answer. Replacing the two lines within the `if` block with the two lines in your answer will give very strange results. If you meant something else, you haven't explained it. You've also misspelled one of the variables.